# Programming Language needed to create google chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a google chrome extension that communicates with com ports. I have no idea what language to use though. Any suggestions will be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to talk to COM ports you'll need to use an operating-system-level API, and that requires a plugin, not an extension.

Plugins are privileged code, somewhat akin to kernel drivers. They are typically written in C or similar. An easy way to write a plugin is using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home).

It will take weeks or months to create a working plugin (for the first time).

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extensions use a much higher abstraction layer than that needed to communicate with COM ports.
Therefore it's probably impossible to do that.
If you provide some more information about the use case, maybe we can figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions are small software programs that can modify and enhance the functionality of the Chrome browser. You write them using web technologies such as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

One can create extensions with the enough knowledge of HTML,CSS, JAVASCRIPT, JQUERY.

HTML is used as a content markup language, CSS is used for styling, and JavaScript for scripting. Because Chrome supports HTML5 and CSS3, developers can use the latest open web technologies such as canvas and CSS animations in their extensions. Extensions also have access to several JavaScript APIs that help perform functions like JSON encoding and interacting with the browser.